# In iOS, how can we increase HTTP connection limit per host?

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlconnection, tcp

Using the Xcode networking tool, I analyzed that I am able to establish only 4 TCP connections per host at a time. It seems iOS has a default TCP connection limit of 4 per host.

How can we increase that limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. We can change the `NSURLSession`'s default settings such as `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` or `ShouldUsePipelining` by accessing `[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]`.

```
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration].HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : As stated by the OP this has changed in iOS 8: See [Apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost)

**Original post** :

This is a limit in iOS you cannot change it.

See : [On iOS URL Connection Parallelism and Thread Pools](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/01/on-ios-url-connection-parallelism-and.html)